# PHP JSON with jsoncallback

Tags: php, jquery, json

```
$Data = 'jQuery1111014795648865074196_1507974360762({"type":"my","start":1,"end":20,"total":20})';
 $D2 = json_decode($Data);
echo $Result_Count = $D2->{'total'};
```

Above code not working for me but if I remove `jQuery1111014795648865074196_1507974360762()` so it's working fine

Working example:

```
$Data = '{"type":"my","start":1,"end":20,"total":20}';
$D2 = json_decode($Data);
echo $Result_Count = $D2->{'total'}
```

Comment: what is this -> `jQuery1111014795648865074196_1507974360762` and from where it coming? and why you are adding it?At which end it's not working `php` or `jQuery`?

Comment: it's coming from API.

it's jsoncallback...i can't removed it because it's coming from api.

PHP end not working...

Comment: Please show your code. As well as can you provide API url.(add both in your question)

Comment: It's up to you to specify the JSONP callback wrapper. Generally jQuery pass a get parameter named "callback" on its own that contains the temporary callback name that will allow you to retrieve the payload.

Comment: Geolim4 @ yes you're right but without callback in API return result is null ....

Comment: Updated my question ... please check now

Comment: @HiteshAghara If any of the provided solution work for you, please be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$Data = 'jQuery1111014795648865074196_1507974360762({"type":"my","start":1,"end":20,"total":20})';
$Data = preg_replace("/^[\w]+[(]|[)]$/", '', $Data);
$D2 = json_decode($Data);
echo $Result_Count = $D2->total;
```

This uses `regex` to remove the prefix and brackets from the `json` string.

Comment: @HiteshAghara No, this will not interrupter the json string. As it will start from the beginning of the string stop at `(` remove that and then remove the last `)`. If there is any of these characters in between it will not change them.

Answer (score 1):

If jQuery1111014795648865074196_1507974360762 is static then you use php's str_replace function to remove it along with brackets.

Comment: If its not static then the length of jQuery1111014795648865074196_1507974360762 will must be same in the response try substring function of php. Otherwise the last option would be to use strpos and find the position of first opening bracket and remove the content before The string using substring function